# What happens if printer runs out of ink, mid-print? Can I replace the cartridge and continue printing?

Tags: printing, printer

I am specifically interested in pro-ish photographic printers such as the Cannon Pro-1000 or the Epson P900. I am interested in printing long-ish prints (about 48"). I am concerned about getting 40" into the print and getting the "out of ink" warning. I know that both of these printers use an ink reservoir system, and there will still be ink in said reservoir. And, no, I would have no intention or desire to continue printing without replacing the cartridge immediately. The question is:

After I replace said cartridge, will the printer continue on and finish that print without ruining that print? Or, will I just have to start all over again?

I know it is physically and algorithmically possible to design a printer to do this. The question is: Do either of these printers have said algorithms?

To be very clear: I am **NOT** talking about waiting until the print head physically runs dry. I am talking about when the "red X" indicator comes on in the printer management software, which occurs well before the reservoir runs out and the print head runs dry.

Comment: While I'm not sure that you can change cartridges mid print, the amount of ink used by an inkjet printer can vary by how often you use it.  The less often it's used, the more often it will have to do a cleaning cycle - which wastes ink.  So I think pragmatically it comes down to you learning the behavior of what ever printer you have and estimating how big a print job you can complete.

Comment: You probably should contact the provider or manufacturer, or sales department for the specific info.

Comment: I have the Canon Pro 1000 - but as of now I never had a cartridge go out in mid print. I also had a search and could not find any info on this.

Comment: Likely, if printing stopped and restarted, there would be a band on the print. How bad it would be depends on many variables, e.g., did air get into line during changeover that has to be purged by an automatic cleaning cycle. Though I cannot tell if large-tank printers such as the Epson Ecotank, meet your print standards, they hold far more ink than could be used in a 48" print job, and adding ink can be done without opening the feed line. This one has a 8.4" x 47.2" max size: https://epson.com/For-Home/Printers/Inkjet/EcoTank-ET-2760-All-in-One-Cartridge-Free-Supertank-Printer/p/C11CG22203